# Loading sources of image swiper from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I made a book that consist of 140 images as pages and each image is about 40kB. i don't want put them in `Drawables Folder` because of security lack . so I should load images in sqlite and use [MikeOrtiz_TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) "ViewPagerExample" class for swipe and zoom pages.

My problem is how to load images from database to image swiper  array:  `int[] images` or any array (I'm a beginner! explain this with detail please)

```
package com.ortiz.touch;

import com.example.touch.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ViewPagerExampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpager_example);
        ExtendedViewPager mViewPager = (ExtendedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new TouchImageAdapter());
    }

    static class TouchImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private static int[] images = {
            R.drawable.nature_1, R.drawable.nature_2, R.drawable.nature_3, R.drawable.nature_4, R.drawable.nature_5
        };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(container.getContext());
            img.setImageResource(images[position]);
            container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            return img;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

    }
}
```

Are there also any suggestions except those explained?

Comment: does `because of security lack` mean you want to make it more difficuilt to steal your images? Do you need help about encrypting/decrypting images?

Comment: yes and I choose database to use sqlcipher to encrypt it. do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

save to database:
       bitmap to byte[]; 
user image: 
       byte[] to bitmap;
but its useless;
people can get your source if they want;

Answer (score 0):

you can get Images from DB as Blob and can convert into Bitmap array

```
  String query = "SELECT * FROM '" + tablename+ "'";
      Cursor tileCursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);//create a database object
    ArrayList<Bitmap> images=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    while(!tileCursor.isAfterLast())
    {
    byte[] bitmapdata =tileCursor.getBlob(tileCursor.getColumnIndex("Imagecolumnname"));
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
     images.Add(bitmap );
  tileCursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

Then set it using

```
  @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(container.getContext());
        img.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
        container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return img;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks rajan...I most test it, but do you think because of using image swiper i need buffer for example 4 bitmaps to prevent jitter? or simply by every swip load proper bitmap?

Comment: every time it loads Bitmap and to avoid OutOfMemoryException you can compress bitmap also before adding to list

Comment: yep now i updated the answer to your need its cursor to read blob from DB